# Drawing a 5-stage binary LFSR with feedback Sm+5= Sm + Sm+1

Tags: cryptography

Any guidance on how to draw this would be greatly appreciated I know this is more of a visual thing but I also want to go on to determine all the possible (different) cycles that are generated by this LFSR. What is its characteristic polynomial and what is the order?